# How can I change font-family to local font in Material UI Table in Next.js project?

Tags: next.js, material-ui, font-family

global.css
`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Reset";
  src: url('../../public/assets/font/reset.ttf');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Home.module.css
`

```
reset-font{
  font-family: 'Reset', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

`

Table/index.jsx
`

```
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css';

 <div  className={styles.testFont}> 
      <Toolbar
        sx={{
          pl: { sm: 0 },
          pr: { xs: 1, sm: 1 },
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "black",
          color: "#ff00c0",
        }}
      >
        <Typography
            sx={{ 
              flex: '1 1 100%'
             }}
            variant="h6"
            id="tableTitle"
            component="div"

          >
            JOBS
          </Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </div>
```

`

But it isn't working and searched about related posts over here but there're only posts about using Theme.
Is there any other efficient way to figure it out?

I find other ways.
But when import font from local it's asking to load plugin.
And I'm not sure about other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue through createMuiTheme function.

Below code works on latest MUI, React, Next version

```
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Reset',
    ].join(','),
  }
});


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {  

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <XLayout_home>
        <main className={`${reset.variable} font-sans`}>
          {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps}/>)}
        </main>
      </XLayout_home>  
    </ThemeProvider>
  )

}
```